# ansible custom filter fails when importing python library

Tags: python, path, ansible, jinja2, boto3

I'm trying to write a custom Jinja2 filter in Ansible.

I am able to write a trivial filter.
However for the actual use case I have in mind, I want to do `import boto3`.

When I run `pip list | grep boto3`, I see that it is installed.
When I run `python -c 'import boto3'`, that runs successfully.

But when I insert `import boto3` up the top of my custom filter, Ansible fails to load it.

## MWE

Directory structure:

```
  - filter_plugins/
     - custom.py
  - playbook.yaml
```

`custom.py`:

```
import hashlib # I can import some things, not others

print("custom filter file loaded")
class FilterModule(object):

    def _square(self,x):
        return(int(x)*int(x))  

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'my_square': self._square
        }
```

`playbook.yaml`:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:

    - name: test custom filter
      assert:
        that:
          - "( 2 | my_square ) == 4"
      tags:
        - test
```

When I invoke this with:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml
```

The playbook runs sucessfully.
I can also see "custom filter file loaded" printed out by Ansible

But when I append `import boto3` to the top, the playbook fails.

- "custom filter file loaded" is *not* printed out by Ansible.
- The error message is:

> fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '( 2 | my_square ) == 4' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: no filter named 'my_square'. String: {% if ( 2 | my_square ) == 4 %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}"}

## Questions:

- Is this because I'm using `connection: local`, or because Ansible uses the `PATH` of a non-interactive shell?
- How can I debug why custom filters fail? It took me a lot of time to figure out that the `import boto3` line was causing the failure. Ansible seems to import the custom filter file at the start of the playbook run (and sometimes other times), catches the error, then continues on until I try to use the filter.
- Is this a Python 2 vs Python 3 thing? Which does Python use? (I did `pip install boto3`, and I don't have `pip3` installed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: "`Is this a Python 2 vs Python 3 thing? Which does Python use?`"

A: Yes. Very probably `ansible-playbook playbook.yaml` uses Python 2. Run the playbook in verbose mode

```
ansible-playbook -vvv playbook.yaml
```

and find the version of Python. For example

```
python version = 2.7.15+ (default, Nov 27 2018, 23:36:35) [GCC 7.3.0]
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it's actually a python 2.6 vs python 2.7 thing. `ansible-playbook -vvv` shows 2.6, and `sys.path` inside the custom filter shows 2.6. But `python --version` in the terminal shows 2.7. The Ansible docs [*mention*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/dev_guide/developing_python3.html#minimum-version-of-python-3-x-and-python-2-x) that there are issues with boto and 2.6, but don't say exactly how to get around them. Any idea how I can tell Ansible to use python 2.7?

Comment: Ah yes. The solution was to do `yum uninstall ansible` then `pip-3.6 install ansible` (or `pip install ansible`)